# What kind of parsing supported by ANTLR4?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, ll-grammar, lr-grammar

I was recently using antlr4 for one of my projects. But I have no idea what kind of parsing method they are using. While i was searching some resources i found a [research paper](http://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf) which says ANTLR4 uses a parser called `ALL(*)`. But i have no idea about that method and also I could not find any resource which explains `ALL(*)` method

Could anyone explain is `ALL(*)` the only method used by ANTLR4 and are there any web resources on `ALL(*)` method which explains it simple manner ?

Thank you

Comment: They do have a web site and several books.

Comment: ALL stands for adaptive LL-star - the latter meaning that it is an LL (top-down) parser with unlimited lookahead. That and the adaptive nature is all explained [here](http://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf).